# change brightness in ipad

Tags: ipad

I am developing one application for iPad and iPhone, I want to make a slider control to change the brightness of the screen as per the slider value. Can any one help me to solve my problem

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with public APIs. You could put an overlay to make the screen darker, but you can't adjust the hardware brightness.

Comment: thanks for reply but

how to put the layer and make it darker 
cna you provide me that code...........

Comment: Just put a view over everything, set usserInteractionEnabled=NO and adjust the alpha.

Comment: keep in mind that popovers and other views may still get on top of your overlay view